# Asterisk thinks outbound call is to fax machine

Tags: asterisk

A user recently notified me that whenever they attempt to dial into a conference call at another company, the phone call would get dropped after 5 seconds or so. They also indicated that when the same number is called using a cell phone, there were no issues. I found the following entries in log file.

```
[May 4 11:58:20] VERBOSE[24063] app_dial.c: -- DAHDI/1-1 is ringing
[May 4 11:58:20] VERBOSE[24063] app_dial.c: -- DAHDI/1-1 answered SIP/145-00000005
[May 4 11:58:24] WARNING[24063] rtp.c: Don't know how to represent 'f'
[May 4 11:58:24] VERBOSE[24063] chan_dahdi.c: -- Redirecting DAHDI/1-1 to fax extension
[May 4 11:58:24] VERBOSE[24063] pbx.c: -- Executing [h@macro-dialout-trunk:1] Macro("SIP/145-00000005", "hangupcall,") in new stack
[May 4 11:58:24] VERBOSE[24063] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:1] GotoIf("SIP/145-00000005", "1?theend") in new stack
```

I have not been able to determine a solution. Any insight or suggestions on solving this problem are appreciated. 
(Using FreePBX v2.9; Asterisk v1.6.2.15.1; CentOS 5.5 (Final); Sangoma A102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also tried modiying chan_dahdi.conf, but that did not work. 
Final solution was to modify these settings (changing from YES to NO) in /etc/wanrouter/wanpipe1.conf

```
TDMV_HW_DTMF         = NO            # YES: receive dtmf events from hardware
TDMV_HW_FAX_DETECT   = NO            # YES: receive fax 1100hz events from hardware
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add into  file

/etc/asterisk/sip_general_custom.conf

```
faxdetect=no
```

Comment: Thanks @arheops for posting possible solution. Unfortunately, I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: ops,sorry. you have dahdi, not sip. check file chan_dahdi.conf